# Constructing the Bruhat-Tits building of $SL_2$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am trying to understand how to construct the Bruhat-Tits building of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. I am reading the general construction of the semisimple Bruhat-Tits building of a connected reductive group. I will explain what I think is the construction (but please correct me if anything I'm saying is wrong) of the building as a quotient of $SL_2 \times A$ by an equivalence relation.

Let $T$ be the maximal torus of diagonal matrices. The apartment $A$ of $SL_2$ associated to $T$ is the tensor product of the cocharacters of $T$ with $\mathbb{R}$: it can be identified with $\mathbb{R}$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ let $U_x$ be the subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ generated by the identity, the matrices with 1's on the diagonal, 0 on the lower left, and $c \in \mathbb{Q_p}$ such that val$(c) \geq -2x$, and the matrices with 1's on the diagonal, 0 on the top right, and $d$ with val$(d) \geq 2x$. Let $N$ be the normalizer of $T$ (so the monomial matices with entries in $\mathbb{Q}_p$). It acts on $A$:

$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
t & 0 \\
0 & t^{-1} \\
\end{array} \right)$ sends $x$ to $x-$val$(t)$ and

$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & t\\
-t^{-1} & 0 \\
\end{array} \right)$ sends $x$ to $-x-$val$(t)$.

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p) \times A$ by:

$(g,x) \sim (h,y)$ if there is $n \in N$ such that $nx=y$ and $g^{-1}hn \in U_x$. The quotient is the building $X$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

The apartment $A$ can be identified as a subset of $X$ by $x \mapsto$ the class of $(Id, x)$.

Somehow this is a 3-regular tree. This is what I don't understand. The extended building of $GL_2$ can be thought of as the set of additive norms on $(\mathbb{Q}_p)^2$. If $T_1$ is the diagonal torus of GL$_2$, the apartment can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the elements of the apartment can be identified with additive norms by sending $(a_1,a_2)$ to the norm $\phi$ defined by $\phi(x_1,x_2)=$inf$\{val(x_1)-a_1,val(x_2)-a_2\}$.

$\mathbb{R}$ acts on these norms by translating the values of the norm. We can identify the apartment of $SL_2$ with norms-on-$\mathbb{Q}_p^2$-up-to-translation: $a \in \mathbb{R}$ would correspond to the equivalence class of the norm $\phi(x_1,x_2)=$inf$\{val(x_1),val(x_2)-a\}$.

$SL_2$ acts on the building $X$: $g$ sends the class of $(h,x)$ to the class of $(gh,x)$. This corresponds to an action of the norms: $g$ sends $\phi$ to the norm $g\phi$ defined by $g\phi(v)=\phi(gv)$ where $v \in \mathbb{Q}_p^2$.

If all this is true, then two equivalent pairs $(g,x)$ and $(h,y)$ of $SL_2 \times A$ should give the same norm-up-to-translation. But I don't think this is true.

My question is: How does one go from the abstract construction of the building to get a tree? I haven't found any literature that explains this.

Comment: Did you try Serre's book "Trees"?

Comment: Yes. Serre's book doesn't have an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this but actually the Bruhat-Tits building of $G = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ is only a $3$-regular tree when $p=2$.  In general it will be a $(p+1)$-regular tree.  You can see this by looking at the standard maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and reducing it modulo $p$.

If you take the copy of $(0,1) \subset A$ and think of it as being inside your building $X$, then the translates $g.(0,1) : g \in G$ will be the **chambers** of the building.  You can show that the stabilizer $B$ of $(0,1)$ (which is the same as the stabilizer of each its points) is the Iwahori subgroup

$$B = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p) : c \in p \mathbb Z_p\}.$$

The stabilizer of the point $0 \in A$ is the standard maximal compact subgroup $K = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$, and the stabilizer of $1 \in A$ is the other standard maximal compact subgroup $$K' = \begin{pmatrix} p \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}K\begin{pmatrix} p \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

The points $0$ and $1$ are the **faces** of the chamber $(0,1)$.  The other faces of the building $X$ are by definition the $G$-translates of these faces.

You can show that $X$ is the disjoint union of three types of subsets: chambers, faces of type $0$, and faces of type $1$.  If $g.(0,1)$ is a chamber of $X$, then $g.0$ and $g.1$ are its faces.

Anyway, seeing that $X$ is a $(p+1)$-tree comes down to verifying a few things:

- $K, K', B$ are self-normalizing subgroups.  There are no subgroups between $G$ and $B$ except for $K$ and $K'$.
- Chambers of $X$ are in bijection with Iwahori subgroups, i.e. conjugates of $B$.  If $g.(0,1)$ is a chamber, then it has stabilizer $gBg^{-1}$.
- Faces of type $0$ are in bijection with subgroups of type $K$.  If $g.0$ is a face, then it has stabilizer $gKg^{-1}$.  The same for faces of type $1$ and subgroups of type $K'$.
- A face with stabilizer $K''$ is the face of a given chamber with stabilizer $B''$ if and only if $B'' \subset K''$.

Now you can see how to define a graph which encapsulates $X$: the vertices are the faces, and the edges are the chambers.  Each chamber has exactly two faces, so this makes sense.

So from here, you can fix a face $g.0$, say of type $0$ (type $1$ will be gotten by conjugating everything by $\begin{pmatrix} p \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$), and ask: how many chambers it is a face of?  Without loss of generality, we can assume $g = e$, and we see this is the same as asking how many Iwahori subgroups, i.e. conjugates of $B$, does $K$ contain?

Because $B$ is self normalizing, this is the same as calculating the index $[K : B]$.  For this, we let $\mathcal G = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$, and $\mathcal P$ the image of $B$ in $\mathcal G$ under the reduction modulo $p$ map.  Then $\mathcal P$ is the standard parabolic subgroup of $\mathcal G$, $K$ maps surjectively onto $\mathcal G$, and by the first isomorphism theorem,

$$[K : B] = [\mathcal G : \mathcal P]$$

By the Bruhat-decomposition, this has $p+1$ elements.  This is how you see that each vertex has $p+1$ edges, i.e. $X$ has the structure of a $(p+1)$-tree.